# How can you make a Grails configuration error fatal?

Tags: grails

If I have a Grails configuration file with bad syntax, I would like it to be a fatal error. Currently, ConfigurationHelper catches all exceptions and makes a WARN-level log entry:

2013-04-16 12:06:13,687 [main] WARN  cfg.ConfigurationHelper  - Unable to load specified config location file:/opt/grails-config/Turbine-config.groovy : startup failed:
script13661391736182105595282.groovy: 95: expecting '}', found '' @ line 95, column 1.
1 error

How can I make the application fail to start instead? Or at least produce an ERROR-level log entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thought would be to check for the absence of a config value in the `BootStrap` `init` closure:

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        if (!grailsApplication.config.myValueFromExternalConf) {
            log.error(...)
            // and/or throw something...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an effective way of making sure the config file was read!

Comment: @JoshuaSwink FYI, I just ran across this plugin, which looks like a more robust & complete solution: http://grails.org/plugin/validate-config